# Dependency property error

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I am learning dependency properties. I read many posts & books but still I am not clear.

The program shown below is which I wrote to learn. Some error in that, please help in resolving. I have questions.

1. The main use of custom Dependency property element is for the notification of change?
2. I found an 'IsDefaultProperty' code for **Button** in a WPF text book. It means '**IsDefault**' property is a dependency property?
3. Why they shown that code? It means, internally, in Button class, its defined like that? 
   (They showed internal code?) or they showed how to define as custom?

Here is my code:

```
namespace DependencyProperties
{
    public class Contact
    {
        private int id=100;
        private string name="shri";
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPresentProperty;

        public int ID
        {
            get { return id; }
        }
        public string NAME
        {
            get { return name; }
        }

        static Contact()
        {
            IsPresentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsPresent", typeof(bool),typeof(Contact),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsPresentChanged)));
        }

        public bool Present
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(Contact.IsPresentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(Contact.IsPresentProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnIsPresentChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {  

        }
    }
}
```

And I see the error:

```
> Error: GetValue and SetValue does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The main use of custom Dependency property element is for the
>   notification of change?

No, that can also be arranged by having the class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well. Dependency properties to provide change notifications, but the real rationale is something different. See [Why dependency properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723756/why-dependency-properties) and [How is the WPF property system economical?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5552943/50079)

> I found an 'IsDefaultProperty' code for Button in a WPF text book. It
>   means 'IsDefault' property is a dependency property?

Yes. Naming a field "FooBarProperty" is the WPF convention for defining dependency properties; you can check the docs for [`IsDefaultProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefaultproperty.aspx) to see that it's indeed a dependency property, and even the [`IsDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault.aspx) documentation has a section called "dependency property information".

> Why they shown that code? It means, internally, in Button class, its
>   defined like that? (They showed internal code?) or they showed how to
>   define as custom?

I 'm not sure what "that" code is, but yes, the property is almost certainly defined like that in `Button` ("almost" because I 'm not sure what you are referring to).

> Error: GetValue and SetValue does not exist in the current context

That's because you are not deriving from [`DependencyObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx).

Answer (score 23):

`DependencyProperty` instances must be defined on instances of `DependencyObject`.  So, your class must derive from `DependencyObject`, or one of its subclasses.  Many types in WPF derive from this, including `Button`.

So to get your code working in this case, you must use:

```
public class Contact : DependencyObject
{
    // ...
```

This is why you are receiving an error on `GetValue` and `SetValue` -- they are defined on `DependencyObject`.